# How to show multiple web view links on Xcode under one UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

Suppose I have an app with 3 buttons each opening 3 different UIWebView view controllers. Instead of having 3 separate view controllers for each button, I want to have 1 UIWebView view controllers and depending on the button that is pressed, that is what will show on the UIWebView.

This is just an example of what I am talking about

firstViewController

Button 1 opens Yahoo

Button 2 opens Google

Button 3 opens Bing

secondViewController

if button1 is pressed, show Yahoo on the UIWebView
if button2 is pressed, show google on the UIWebView
if button3 is pressed, show bing o the UIWebView

How do I come up with this?

Comment: simple man, which one you are used, storyboard or xib

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I use storyboards

Comment: set button tags like 1 2 3 respectively . and on button press send that to viewController having webview. And based on tag value ,load content of particular link in webview

Comment: or simply send 1 ,2 ,3 integer values to other view controller having webview whne button1 ,button2 or button 3 is pressed . check property value on next view controller and load content respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iOS each object contains own `tags` if you are interest use tags else other options.

assume that your button1.tag=10,  button2.tag=20 and  button3.tag=30

set the global string for in .h file

```
NSString *activecheck;

// assign the single method for all buttons in touchup inside method

- (IBAction)button_GetDeals:(UIButton*)sender {


switch (sender.tag)
{
    case 10:
      activecheck=@"1";

        break;
        case 20:

          activecheck=@"2";
        break;
          case 30:

          activecheck=@"3";
        break;
 }



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"secondviewcontrolleridentidiername"]) {

    secondViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController. buttontype = activecheck;
}
```

// this is your second view controller

```
@interface secondViewController : UIViewController


 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *buttontype;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;

@end
```

in your .m file  `viewdidload`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if ([buttontype isEqualtoString:@"1"])

  NSString *strURL = @"http://www.google.com";
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
  NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webiew loadRequest:urlRequest];
 }
```

just like follow the another two condition for bing and yahoo ....

Comment: if you need assistance I surely hope with you

Comment: Okay I see, would this be the same if the buttons are in separate view controllers this time?

Comment: and I also import the first view controller to the second right?

Comment: first r u understand my concept , what I did , k just import the second view controller.h  in first view controller

Comment: Can you explain the first part of your code for the first view controller? I have 3 buttons.

Comment: ya u have 3 buttons and assign the different tag what u like , second assign the common method for 3 buttons, finally i assign the one global string for known to which buttons is selected , if u click that button it identify the tags, thats all friend

Comment: welcome my friend have a nice day , if u need assistance karthik.saral@gmail.com(FB, Twitter, stack overflow, gmail and Skype)

Answer (score 0):

Button 1 opens Yahoo

In its action
write:

```
[webView loadRequest:YOUR REQUEST_YAHOO];
// reload your view
```

Button 2 opens Google

In its action
write:

```
[webView loadRequest:YOUR REQUEST_GOOGLE];
// reload your view
```

Button 3 opens Bing

In its action
write:

```
[webView loadRequest:YOUR REQUEST_Bing];
// reload your view
```

For reload your view you can use:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay]; //such methods
```